# Nothing is populated from ArrayList to ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to populate some items from PHP to Android using ListView

```
    public class ChooseCategory extends ListActivity {

            private ListView lv;
            ArrayAdapter<FoodStores> arrayAdapter;

            private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
            private ArrayList<FoodStores> storefoodList;
            // JSON parser class
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            //ids
            private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
            private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
            private String URL_STORES = "http://www.123.com/get_stores.php";

        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                //lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
                 lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                storefoodList = new ArrayList<FoodStores>();
                new GetFoodStores().execute();


            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FoodStores>  (this,R.layout.restaurant_list,storefoodList );


     private class GetFoodStores extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                ServiceHandlerFood jsonParserFood = new ServiceHandlerFood();
                String json = jsonParserFood.makeServiceCall(URL_STORES, ServiceHandlerFood.GET);
                Log.e("Response: ", " > " + json);
                if(json != null){
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                        if(jsonObj != null){
                            JSONArray storeListFood = jsonObj.getJSONArray("storelistfood");
                            for(int i = 0; i < storeListFood.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject storeFoodObj = (JSONObject) storeListFood.get(i);
                                FoodStores foodStores = new FoodStores(storeFoodObj.getInt("id"),storeFoodObj.getString("STORENAME"));
                                storefoodList.add(foodStores);

                            }
                        }
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.e("JSON Data", "No data received from server");
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }
        }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="{relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

restaurant_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nasilemak2" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Itemname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The error that I got is that it only shows blank screen and it crashed after a minute. I would like to populate the ListView using ArrayList from PHP.

Comment: Post the crash logs.

Comment: I think it should be webservice not php or may be you can say web services which is implemented in PHP.

Comment: I think you have to make custom Adapter for your problem by extending class with `ArrayAdapter<FoodStores>`.

Comment: if any of the below answers satisfy your query, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

You didn't provide all classes so some classes are provided by me.
Here you are:

[image: Screenshot]

ChooseCategory.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ChooseCategory extends ListActivity {

    private ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter<FoodStores> arrayAdapter;

    private static final String TAG = "XXX";
    private ArrayList<FoodStores> storefoodList;
    // JSON parser class
    // JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    // ids
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private String URL_STORES = "http://echo.jsontest.com/id/1/STORENAME/Perogi";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        storefoodList = new ArrayList<FoodStores>();
        new GetFoodStores().execute();

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FoodStores>(this,
                R.layout.restaurant_list, R.id.Itemname, storefoodList);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    private class GetFoodStores extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            ServiceHandlerFood jsonParserFood = new ServiceHandlerFood();
            String json = jsonParserFood.makeServiceCall(URL_STORES,
                    "TEST");
                    //ServiceHandlerFood.GET);
            Log.e("Response: ", " > " + json);
            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    if (jsonObj != null) {
                        JSONArray storeListFood = jsonObj
                                .getJSONArray("storelistfood");
                        for (int i = 0; i < storeListFood.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject storeFoodObj = (JSONObject) storeListFood
                                    .get(i);
                            FoodStores foodStores = new FoodStores(
                                    storeFoodObj.getInt("id"),
                                    storeFoodObj.getString("STORENAME"));
                            storefoodList.add(foodStores);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "No data received from server");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Foodstores.java:

```
public class FoodStores {

    int id;
    String name;
    public FoodStores(int id, String string) {
        this.id=id;
        name=string;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }

}
```

ServiceHandlerFood.java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;

public class ServiceHandlerFood {

    public static final String GET = "GET";

    public String makeServiceCall(String uRL_STORES, String get2) {
        if ("TEST".equals(get2))
            return "{'storelistfood':[{'id':1, 'STORENAME':'Arbys'},{'id':2, 'STORENAME':'Perogi'},{'id':3, 'STORENAME':'McDonalds'}]}";

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(
                new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uRL_STORES);
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            // json is UTF-8 by default
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Oops
        } finally {
            try {
                if (inputStream != null)
                    inputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception squish) {
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

The rest of files was untouched.

Answer (score 3):

Move this line in onPost method:

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FoodStores>  `(this,R.layout.restaurant_list,storefoodList );`
```

Like this

```
 @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
                super.onPostExecute(result);
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FoodStores>  (this,R.layout.restaurant_list,storefoodList );
                lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }
```

**Edit :**

And change `"this"` to `getApplicationContext()` like this

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FoodStores>  (getApplicationContext(),R.layout.restaurant_list,storefoodList );
```

**Edit 1:**

Replace the following to

```
 lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

this

```
 lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Comment: I did that and it says Cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter

Comment: It gives java.lang.NullPointerException at lv.setAdapter line

Comment: What is the value in this Log Log.e("Response: ", " > " + json);

Comment: E/Response:﹕ > {"storelistfood":[{"id":"1","STORENAME":"PizzaHut"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79940/discussion-between-amsheer-and-soft1234).

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with your code is, the default implementation of the ArrayAdapter needs a TextView in which it will display its list items as strings. If not provided, it will throw exception like

> 06-22 21:22:42.535: E/AndroidRuntime(6531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-22 21:22:42.535: E/AndroidRuntime(6531):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID
>   to be a TextView 06-22 21:22:42.535: E/AndroidRuntime(6531):  at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
>   06-22 21:22:42.535: E/AndroidRuntime(6531):   at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)

The simplest solution will be to just replace

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FoodStores>  (this,R.layout.restaurant_list,storefoodList );
```

with

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FoodStores>  (this,R.layout.restaurant_list,R.id.Itemname,storefoodList);
```

Please note the additional parameter **R.id.Itemname** which is the TextView in your layout that the ArrayAdapter needs to display the content.

Please also remember to override the toString() method in your FoodStores to return some logical string like the name if not done already (as suggested by @Alex above).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I`m not sure about it, but this line is not good,because:

```
             storefoodList = new ArrayList<FoodStores>();
            new GetFoodStores().execute();
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<FoodStores>  (this,R.layout.restaurant_list,storefoodList );
```

You give an empty arrayList to the adapter, because AsyncTaks is still loading the content. So in this case, the adapter cache an empty list, and it`s going to provide to the listview when you call the lw.setAdapter(adapter) at onPostExecute. 
If you wouldn`t like to change the architecture of your app then,You should call **notifydatasetchanged**() after you set the adapter in onPostExecute.

OR you can initialize the adapter with the updated list, onPostExecute, and set it to the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 problems here

1. you need to create a custom adapter that extends from
   ArrayAdapter
       you cannot use ArrayAdapter directly [enter link description here][1]   [1]:
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html
2. either need to create the array adapter in onPostExecute or you
       need to tell your adapter that arraylist haschanged
3. if your
           activity extends listactivity then as you did listview's id in xml
           should be @android:id/list but then  ListView lv = getListView() or
           your activity just extends Activity and listview's id is in xml
           should be @+id/list then  ListView lv =
           (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list)

Answer (score 0):

try to implement image with Picasso and do more  one thing that please do have any other web service so please check this web service in this code so it will clear that the code will working correctly or not. After that that will be more easily for you. do let me know if any.